# The Response Stream was null or empty QBO V3 API

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am using the NuGet package "API for QuickBooks V3" and I keep receiving this Exception and I don't know where to go from here. I am authenticating correctly and was able to submit a purchase object that was created successfully but when I tried to Update the object I started receiving this error and can't get past it. I read a post about throttling but I am not making 200 requests/minute, at most I'm making right now is 5 - 10. Just looking for some guidance cause I am lost.

Stacktrace:
at Intuit.Ipp.Core.CoreHelper.CheckNullResponseAndThrowException(String response) at Intuit.Ipp.QueryFilter.QueryService`1.ExecuteIdsQuery(String idsQuery, QueryOperationType queryOperationType) at Intuit.Ipp.QueryFilter.QueryService`1.Execute(Expression expression, Boolean isToIdsQueryMethod, String& idsQuery) at Intuit.Ipp.LinqExtender.QueryProvider`1.ExecuteQuery(IBucket bucket, IModifiableCollection`1 items, Boolean isToIdsQueryMethod, String& idsQuery) at Intuit.Ipp.LinqExtender.Query`1.ProcessItem(BucketImpl item)

```
    ServiceContext serviceContext = getServiceContext(profile);
 QueryService<Account> queryService = new QueryService<Account>(serviceContext);
 return queryService.Where(c => c.AccountType == type).ToList();

private static ServiceContext getServiceContext(ProfileCommon profile)
        {
            var consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString();
            var consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"].ToString();
            OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(profile.OAuthAccessToken, profile.OAuthAccessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);

            var serviceType = IntuitServicesType.None;
            switch (profile.DataSource)
            {
                case "QBD":
                    serviceType = IntuitServicesType.QBD;
                    break;
                default:
                    serviceType = IntuitServicesType.QBO;
                    break;
            }

            return new ServiceContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationToken"].ToString(), profile.RealmId, serviceType, oauthValidator);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked through the V3 .Net SDK and can get the response for the above query-

```
QueryService<Account> queryService = new QueryService<Account>(context);
var re1= queryService.Where(c => c.AccountType == AccountTypeEnum.Expense).ToList();
```

Please check that for the account type you are passing you are using the AccountTypeEnum and also that type has some matching records.

Comment: the issue was actually that the intuit api was down yesterday. thanks for the answer though.